# I am trying to install cmdline-tools within docker container, I am facing following problem

Tags: android, flutter, ubuntu, dockerfile, android-sdk-manager

I am trying to install cmdline-tools within docker container, I am facing the following problem:

```
 => ERROR [dev_container_auto_added_stage_label 12/16] RUN sdkmanager --i  3.7s
------
 > [dev_container_auto_added_stage_label 12/16] RUN sdkmanager --install "cmdline-tools;latest":
#0 3.680 Traceback (most recent call last):
#0 3.680   File "/usr/bin/sdkmanager", line 33, in <module>
#0 3.680 Downloading https://fdroid.gitlab.io/android-sdk-transparency-log/checksums.json.asc into /root/.cache/sdkmanager/checksums.json.asc
#0 3.680     sys.exit(load_entry_point('sdkmanager==0.5.1', 'console_scripts', 'sdkmanager')())
#0 3.680   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/sdkmanager.py", line 1077, in main
#0 3.680     method(args.packages)
#0 3.680   File "/usr/lib/python3/dis
[2023-05-08T06:36:15.579Z] t-packages/sdkmanager.py", line 891, in install
#0 3.681     url = packages[key]
#0 3.681 KeyError: ('cmdline-tools','latest')
------
[2023-05-08T06:36:15.579Z] Dockerfile-with-features:34
--------------------
  32 |     # RUN snap install androidsdk
  33 |     
  34 | >>> RUN sdkmanager --install "cmdline-tools;latest"
  35 |     
  36 |     ENV PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/cmdline-tools/latest/bin
--------------------
```

```
FROM ubuntu:22.04
   

# Clear the cache
RUN apt-get clean && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/*

# Prerequisites
RUN apt update && apt install -y curl git unzip xz-utils zip libglu1-mesa openjdk-8-jdk wget
   


   
# Prepare Android directories and system variables
RUN mkdir -p Android/sdk
ENV ANDROID_SDK_ROOT /Android/sdk
RUN mkdir -p .android && touch .android/repositories.cfg
   
# Set up Android SDK
RUN wget -O sdk-tools.zip https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sdk-tools-linux-4333796.zip
RUN unzip sdk-tools.zip && rm sdk-tools.zip
RUN mv tools Android/sdk/tools
RUN cd Android/sdk/tools/bin && yes | ./sdkmanager --licenses
RUN cd Android/sdk/tools/bin && ./sdkmanager "build-tools;29.0.2" "patcher;v4" "platform-tools" "platforms;android-29" "sources;android-29"
RUN apt install sdkmanager -y


ENV ANDROID_HOME=/Android/Sdk

# RUN apt install snapd -y
# RUN snap install androidsdk

RUN sdkmanager --install "cmdline-tools"

ENV PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/cmdline-tools/latest/bin



# Set up new user
RUN useradd -ms /bin/bash developer
USER developer

ENV PATH "$PATH:/home/developer/Android/sdk/platform-tools"

# download Flutter SDK from Flutter Github repo
RUN git clone https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git /home/developer/flutter

# Set flutter environment path
ENV PATH="/home/developer/flutter/bin:/home/developer/flutter/bin/cache/dart-sdk/bin:${PATH}"


   
# Run basic check to download Dark SDK
RUN flutter doctor

WORKDIR /home/developer
```

Please help me to resolve this.

Comment: Please show us your docker file

Comment: I've already added

Comment: Seems related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76497510).