# While installing cmdline-tools for flutter on Ubuntu, get KeyError: ('cmdline-tools', 'latest')

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, ubuntu

I installed the **android sdk** on Ubuntu 22 using the command:

```
apt install android-sdk
```

When I run

```
flutter doctor
```

I am getting the following error:

```
cmdline-tools component is missing
Run `path/to/sdkmanager --install "cmdline-tools;latest"`
```

I tried installing the missing component using the command:

```
sdkmanager --install "cmdline-tools;latest"
```

but I received an error message saying that the command was not found.

So, I installed it using `apt-get install sdkmanager`

But now, when I run `sdkmanager --install "cmdline-tools;latest"`, I receive the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/sdkmanager", line 33, in <module>
    sys.exit(load_entry_point('sdkmanager==0.5.1', 'console_scripts', 'sdkmanager')())
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/sdkmanager.py", line 1077, in main
    method(args.packages)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/sdkmanager.py", line 891, in install
    url = packages[key]
KeyError: ('cmdline-tools', 'latest')
```

I have no idea how to solve this problem.

Thanks.

**[EDIT]** I don't have GUI access to my machine, only terminal

Comment: Try installing Android Studio directly

Comment: 1. Did you remember to run `apt update` before your `apt install android-sdk`?
2. In `sdkmanager --list` what is the output relevant to `cmdline-tools`? Pick one of them to install.

3. what is your `sdkmanager --version`? Mine is 9.0.

Comment: @justhecuke I just did sdkmanager --list and then sdkmanager --install "tools;26.1.1" (which was the most relevant item to pick), but then doctor still returns the same. (sdk manager version is 25.2.0)

Comment: [I reported this bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/sdkmanager/+bug/2046052). Note that to be more precise with the link provided in [*ailauli69*'s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76497820), https://developer.android.com/studio#command-line-tools-only was more direct in my case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I eventually solved it by installing the real command line tool from [https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line#tools-sdk](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line?hl=fr#tools-sdk)  (not the one using apt install)

Then, in `/root/cmdline-tools/bin` I called:

```
./sdkmanager --sdk_root=/usr/lib/android-sdk/ --install "cmdline-tools;latest"
```